# modelagem mysql - tabela excel para BD

Tags: mysql, modelagem

sou bem iniciante em mysql e gostaria de uma ajuda no seguinte problema:

Tenho uma tabela de excel para votos na matéria/assunto preferido e ela é dividida em várias escolas, por ex:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu transponho estas informações para um BD Mysql em que eu possa consultar por exemplo "quantos votos MATEMÁTICA teve na ESCOLA 02"? Sendo que sempre seriam adicionadas mais Escolas.

Até agora eu criei uma tabela com "Matérias" e uma com "Escolas", mas estou empacado em como cruzar essas duas informações e adicionar os números de votação nela.

Agradeço se alguém puder me dar uma luz, indicar alguma documentação ou aula que endereça este problema.

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta foca o principal foco das `tabelas relacionais` - Pesquisar por este tema encontrará inumeras fontes e documentação.

Sem mais detalhes, e focando apenas no que é perguntado, para o seu modelo ser fléxivel, sugiro a utilização de duas tabelas de referência e uma de interligação.

As tabelas de referência serão:

- matérias;
- escolas;

A tabela de interligação relaciona as dimensões de referência através do identificadores únicos provenientes das tabelas de referências (forçando ou não a utilização de chaves estrangeiras).

Por exemplo:

A tabela `materias_tbl` detalhará as matérias e contêm duas colunas. O identificador único da matéria e o nome da matéria (em alguns casos, pouco usuais e por norma até desaconselhados, o nome e o identificador podem ser a mesma coluna) e lógica idêntica pode ser seguida para a tabela `escolas_tbl` que se focará nas dimensão escolas. As tabelas podem conter mais dados mas a descrição não menciona a sua necessidade pelo que não nos focamos nisso.

A tabela de interligação `materias_escola_tbl` conterá três colunas, duas para a chave de cada uma das tabelas de referência (de forma a relacionar as duas dimensões) e a coluna que regista a contabilização que se pretende que seja feita.

Depois de criadas as tabelas (que não exponho aqui porque a sua criação depende não só do motor usado como de algumas das escolhas tecnicas que se podem fazer) e de estas serem populadas com dados, a obtenção dos dados pedidos pode ser feita com a pesquisa em baixo, usando como ponto de partida a estrutura descrita em cima:

```
SELECT mat.nome, esc.nome, cont.contagem
FROM materias_tbl mat
  JOIN materias_escola_tbl cont ON mat.id = cont.mat_id
  JOIN escolas_tbl esc ON cont.esc_id = esc.id
WHERE esc.nome = 'Escola A' AND mat.nome = 'Matemática'
```

A resposta incluí conceitos de ligação de tabelas também eles essenciais para a compreensão do que é perguntado.

A vantagem de manter as dimensões separadas do que se pretende contabilizar é que aumentar o número de disciplinas ou de escolas não implica uma alteração do modelo - A pesquisa acima continua válida. Dependendo dos requisitos, pode ser necessário reescrever algumas pesquisas se, por exemplo, tiverm sido criadas tabelas pivot similares à apresentada na descrição - Nem todos os motores suportam criação de tabelas pivot ou a sua desconstrução.